# Defining a scope in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a scope in my PropertyAsset model

> scope :asset_not_null, where('asset is not null')

I need to call it from my Property model. Properties have many PropertyAssets

I've seen some examples dotted around but I've not managed to find something that fits what I have here. Assuming it's pretty straight forward?

Comment: Do you want to fetch the property which at least have one propertyasset?

Comment: Try `property.property_assets.asset_not_null`

Comment: `scope :asset_not_null,-> { where('asset is not null')}` . Then do what @Pavan said.

Comment: If I do this: `scope :property.property_assets.asset_not_null, where('asset is not null')` then I get the following error: `undefined method `property_assets' for :property:Symbol`

Comment: Dont do it as scope.Keep your scope like it is now.Just you can call it as property.property_assets.asset_not_null.Dont change your original scope.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks so much chaps. Was going wrong in the controller. Love it when it's an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above all I needed to do was apply the following to my controller method:

```
property = Property.find(params[:id]) 
@property = property.property_assets.asset_content_type_starts_with('image')
```

And simply add the same scope to a the related model.

Simple.